# MySQLi Query not submitting data to my database

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having an issue with a query of MySQLi I'm trying to submit, but no errors are being reported, and absolutely nothing is happening. I've tried multiple methods for a fix, and nothing.

The code:

```
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ISP = GetISP($IP);
$Referrer = DetermineReferrer();
$Browser = GetBrowser();
$OS = GetOS();
$Time = Date("F/j/Y, g:i a");

If($IP){
    mysqli_query($Connection, "INSERT INTO tracker (ip, isp, referrer, browser, os, time)
                               VALUES ('mysqli_real_escape_string($IP)',    
                                       'mysqli_real_escape_string($ISP)',
                                       'mysqli_real_escape_string($Referrer)',
                                       'mysqli_real_escape_string($Browser)',
                                       'mysqli_real_escape_string($OS)',
                                       'mysqli_real_escape_string($Time)')");
}

mysqli_close($Connection);
?>
```

The `If($IP)` was actually a temporary test; that's where I'll be checking if an IP is already in the database, which if possible could you lead me on a track for that?

I appreciate all feedback, whether negative or positive, it can still be helpful.

Edit: I'm going to supply the connect script, although it shouldn't be the problem as an error would display

```
<?php
Define('Host', 'localhost');
Define('Username', 'username');
Define('Password', 'password');
Define('Database', 'database name');

$Connection = mysqli_connect(Host, Username, Password, Database);
?>
```

Out of curiosity, while researching I seen something about using SET instead of VALUES. Could that have anything to do with this?

Comment: Are all those functions, mentioned there, defined?

Comment: Yes, everything is defined from the functions.php file. What's confusing me is, there's no query, no errors, nothing, but shouldn't something be up? My server still reads errors, with incorrect placement, and I've removed parts of the code but after replacing it to fix that specific error, it's just blank, and nothing submits to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use concatenation if you're going to use function calls to construct your string.

```
mysqli_query($Connection, "INSERT INTO tracker (ip, isp, referrer, browser, os, time)
                           VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$IP)."',    
                                   '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$ISP)."',
                                   '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$Referrer)."',
                                   '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$Browser)."',
                                   '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$OS)."',
                                   '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$Time)."')");
```

Comment: I've actually tried that, however it's still not querying. I'm using Define('Host', 'host_name'), etc. to connect, but that shouldn't be a problem, because it connected before. This is rather mind boggling because before I added all the technical stuff for the accounts, it submitted the IP, and ID to the database. Do you need anything else to help identify the problem? I've tried an IDE but the code seems to be fine.

Comment: Check the return value of `mysqli_query`

Comment: Tried multiple times, but I'm getting TRUE

Comment: Try dumping the SQL statement and pasting it into your original question

Comment: Are your column names all in lower-case as you have them `ip, isp, referrer, browser, os, time` or do they reflect the same upper-lower naming convention as in VALUES? `ISP` and `isp` are not the same. @user2943677

Comment: Yes, they're all lower-case for the column names, the variables are only capitalized. 

@Machavity Do you mean the SQL database code itself?

Comment: Echo your SQL query he meant, that can give a clue as to what's going down

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem (and thought this would be the best way to respond.)

So apparently, in my query I needed to do:

```
$Query = mysqli_query($Connection, "INSERT INTO `tracker` (`ip`, `isp`, `referrer`, `browser`, `os`, `time`) VALUES ('$IP', '$ISP', '$Referrer', '$Browser', '$OS', '$Time')");
```

Like that, and the code is submitting my IP, along with returning 1 on the page.

Thanks to all who helped, I appreciate it.

Comment: Actually yes, it did. I just forgot to edit this LOL

Comment: Great, thanks. You're right that answering your own questions is perfectly fine. Don't forget to tick whichever answer was most helpful - you may tick your own if you wish, but if another one was substantially helpful, tick that one - it's how we express appreciation here.